# Is it possible to update a generic property on an abstract base class via the constructor for all sub-classes?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

This may represent poor design, but if you have a generic property in an abstract class that you wish to set via the constructor, can you set the type and value in not only a direct sub-class, but also sub-classes of the subclass?

```
public interface IFirst { }
public interface ISecond { }

public abstract class A<T> {
    public T SomeProperty { get; }

    protected A(T someProperty) {
        SomeProperty = someProperty;
    }
}

public class B : A<IFirst> {
    public B(IFirst someProperty) : base(someProperty) {
    }
}

public class C : B {
    public C(IFirst someProperty) : base(someProperty) {
        //What if I wanted to pass in ISecond as a type to SomeProperty by instantiating this class?
    }
}
```

For all sub-classes of B, I'm locked into using IFirst as the type passed into the constructor.

Is there a design pattern or solution that solves this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: What's the exact problem here? Inheritance models Is-A relationship. You're basically saying that you would like to pass ISecond to the class which can't work with ISecond at all. Imagine we have a reference to A<IFirst> and now we somehow assign C to it. How would you expect it to work? Is there a more precise and accurate description of the problem? What are you trying to model by such hierarchy?

Comment: I'm a little confused... in `B` and `C` `SomeProperty` is of type `IFirst`. Why would you want to assign an `ISecond` to it? Why would you think there would be a way to do this? What are you actually trying to do here? I think we need some more context to understand what you are hoping to achieve. As it is I might suggest you just have a different property that can be an `ISecond`. This could even be a second generic type parameter if you wanted... But I presume there is some reason why it is necessary to assign an object of the wrong type to this property...

Answer (score 2):

You could use another `interface` to derive the two defined `interfaces` from:

```
public interface IBase {}
public interface IFirst : IBase { }
public interface ISecond : IBase { }

public abstract class A<T> {
    public T SomeProperty { get; }

    protected A(T someProperty) {
        SomeProperty = someProperty;
    }
}

public class B : A<IBase> {
    public B(IBase someProperty) : base(someProperty) {
    }
}

public class C : B {
    public C(ISecond someProperty) : base(someProperty) {
        //Works now
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using interface inheritance if you're still bound to IBase? Interfaces don't have any behaviour (yet) so there isn't anything you gain from passing IFirst or ISecond.

Comment: I don't know the use case of OP. But I think, that this answers his question.

Comment: In addition: You wouldn't pass IFirst or ISecond (that makes no sense at all). Instead you pass objects, that implement those Interfaces. IBase will have basic functionality, that is needed by the abstract class A. IFirst and ISecond will then implement higher functionality, that will be needed by B and C. Just what you try to achieve with Interfaces, whenever you use them ;-)

Comment: Yep, I've come up with a theoretical use case but I still think it's kinda 'shady'. Anyway, I hope that's what OP wants.